# install SSL Cert in client machine programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, wcf

I've developed a Desktop application using c# which consume WCF on remote server over the internet i need to secure the communication between WCF Server and the Desktop Application (client) using SSL.
my question is how to install SSL in client machine automatically or by some Code when client installs my application.
thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your above comments that you want to secure the data flowing b/w  the channels.

This can be achieved through c# code - by including the *.cert file as a part of your project and passes in X509Certificate2 class .ctor.

for details, please refer to previous smiliar post -

[Problem SSL Certificate C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713071/problem-ssl-certificate-c-sharp)

hope this helps you !!