# Check for certificate validation error in WebException

Tags: c#, validation, ssl, mono, httpwebrequest

I am using WebRequests on Mono for Android and for some servers the certificate validation fails. I have implemented `ICertificatePolicy` (because `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` was never called - maybe a problem of Mono for Android??) and return true if the user has enabled to accept all certificates in the app settings. If the user disables this settings, I return `false` in case of validation problems. In this case, I'd like to display a message to tell the user that a certificate validation problem occured.

According to [Problem SSL Certificate C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5713071/292233), I implemented a catch block like

```
catch (WebException we)
        {   // If SSL throws exception that will be handled here
            if (we.Status == WebExceptionStatus.TrustFailure)
                throw new Exception( "some nice message" );
        }
```

But this turns out to be useless because the Status is set to SendFailure. How can the exception tell me that the validation failed? Should I go through the `InnerException`s and find the `TlsException` to check if the error code is one of the codes listed in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.icertificatepolicy(v=vs.110).aspx?

Do you have a better solution?

This is the exception I get in case that my `ICertificatePolicy` returns false:

```
 System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailure ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: 0xffffffff800b010a
D/KP2A    (17517):   at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.RemoteValidation (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ClientContext context, AlertDescription description) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
D/KP2A    (17517):   at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.validateCertificates (Mono.Security.X509.X509CertificateCollection certificates) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
D/KP2A    (17517):   at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.ProcessAsTls1 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
D/KP2A    (17517):   at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.HandshakeMessage.Process () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
D/KP2A    (17517):   at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ClientRecordProtocol.ProcessHandshakeMessage (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsStream handMsg) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
D/KP2A    (17517):   at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.InternalReceiveRecordCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
D/KP2A    (17517):   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
D/KP2A    (17517):   at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
D/KP2A    (17517):   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
D/KP2A    (17517):   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
D/KP2A    (17517):   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
D/KP2A    (17517):   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse (System.Net.WebRequest request) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
D/KP2A    (17517):   at System.Net.WebClient.OpenRead (System.Uri address) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found It was to check the full ex stack using the "ToString()" method and see if it contains some text.

```
    catch(WebException ex)
    {
        string fullExStack = ex.ToString();
        if (fullExStack.Contains(("System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed.").ToLower())
            || fullExStack.Contains(("Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Invalid certificate received from server.").ToLower()))

        {
            // Do Anything you need here
            // like throwing a custom exception
        }
    }
```